# How do I set text in a TextField with a tag

Tags: ios, textfield

I create programmatically 12 textfields using one method and I add a tag to each.
Below is the method that creates the textfields, this is called 12 times to create each of the textfields. This works.

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = name;
[textField setTag:tag];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

My question is how do I set the text in each textfield or how do I access it using the tags.

I tried:

```
[textField.2 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat : @"HEY"]];
```

and that does not work.

Comment: Don't use stringWithFormat: this way, it's superfluous. @"HEY" is already a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:2] setText:@"foobar"];
```

It's often a better idea to create an `NSArray` property that contains the text fields though.

Comment: If you do it this way, just make sure you don't use 0 as one of your tags, since that's the default, and other views in the hierarchy will have a 0 tag. But I agree with omz, putting them in an array is probably better.

Comment: This does not work, as I get "No visible @interface for UIView declares selector setText